# Elm 'hello world' example fails when installing elm-html

Tags: elm

Trying a hello world example with Elm 0.17

```
-- Main.elm

import Html exposing (text)

main =
  text "Hello, World!"
```

---

```
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/hello_world_elm$ elm make Main.elm --output=index.html
Some new packages are needed. Here is the upgrade plan.

  Install:
    elm-lang/core 4.0.0

Do you approve of this plan? (y/n) y
Downloading elm-lang/core
Packages configured successfully!
I cannot find module 'Html'.

Module 'Main' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:
  * Misspelled the module name
  * Need to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/hello_world_elm$ elm package install evancz/elm-html
To install evancz/elm-html I would like to add the following
dependency to elm-package.json:

    "evancz/elm-html": "4.0.2 <= v < 5.0.0"

May I add that to elm-package.json for you? (y/n) y


Error: Unable to find a set of packages that will work with your constraints.

justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/hello_world_elm$
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong ? Ubuntu 14.04, Elm 0.17 installed from npm

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package `evancz/elm-html` has been replaced by [`elm-lang/html`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/html/1.0.0/) in version `0.17`. So you should install that.